# TFS Work Item Query based on project and subfolder

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, wiql

So right now I have:

```html
WorkItemStore wis = (WorkItemStore)teamProjCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
            VersionControlServer vcs = teamProjCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var artifactProvider = vcs.ArtifactProvider;

            
            Query query = new Query(
                wis,
                "select * from issue where System.TeamProject = @project",
                new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "project", projectName } }

            );
           
            return query.RunQuery();
```

But there are many folders inside my project. How do I only get the work items associated with that folder instead of my entire project?

Thanks :D

Comment: What do you mean by "folders"? Are you talking about area paths? Iterations?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with tfs. I think the area path. For example, https://{serverPort}/tfs/DSDCollection/{projectName}/GM%201.4%20Development/_git/KO-AD. I would like to only find the work items associated with files in KO-AD

Comment: Then add an area path WHERE clause to the query you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

Your example `https://{serverPort}/tfs/DSDCollection/{projectName}/GM%201.4%20Development/_git/KO-AD` means a repo under a git team project. But work items are on team project level, you can't not filter them for a particular repo.

If you want to filter work items for a particular repo, you have to add tags when you create work items, or you can create area path for each repo. In this way, you cam filter work items as you want.